# In R - how to create function with matrix argument returning a specific matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix

Can I please ask for help on the below:

In R, I am trying to impletent matrices as arguments in functions to return another matrix with the result being certain matrix elements modified.

Due to the above, can you refer me to literature or create a function of which argument is an integer matrix x returning a matrix same size as x with all its odd (or even) numbers doubled.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function like so :

```
double_matrix  <- function(x, double_type = "even") {
   if(double_type == "even")
      x * ((x %% 2 == 0) + 1)
   else
      x * ((x %% 2 == 1) + 1)
}
```

Then test it

```
mat <- matrix(1:20, 5)
#Doubles the even values
double_matrix(mat, "even")

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   12   11   32
#[2,]    4    7   24   17
#[3,]    3   16   13   36
#[4,]    8    9   28   19
#[5,]    5   20   15   40

#Doubles the odd values
double_matrix(mat, "odd")

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    6   22   16
#[2,]    2   14   12   34
#[3,]    6    8   26   18
#[4,]    4   18   14   38
#[5,]   10   10   30   20
```